# Override cldList stop if no statistical differences

Tags: r, loops, statistics

I'm trying to add cld to my data but the cldList stops working the moment it encounters statistical differences. My data has groups with both statistical differences and without, so I need a way to work around this issue. The cldList is part of the `rcompanion` package and is written as follow:

```
cldList = function(formula = NULL,
                   data = NULL, 
                   comparison = NULL, 
                   p.value = NULL, 
                   threshold = 0.05,
                   print.comp = FALSE,
                   remove.space = TRUE,
                   remove.equal = TRUE,
                   remove.zero = TRUE,
                   swap.colon = TRUE,
                   swap.vs = FALSE,
                    ...)
  {
    if(!is.null(formula)){
      p.value     = eval(parse(text=paste0("data","$",all.vars(formula[[2]])[1])))
      comparison  = eval(parse(text=paste0("data","$",all.vars(formula[[3]])[1])))
    }
    Comparison = (as.numeric(p.value) <= threshold)
    
    if (sum(Comparison) == 0){stop("No significant differences.", call.=FALSE)}         # THIS LINE HERE #
    
    if(remove.space == TRUE) {comparison = gsub(" ",  "",  comparison)}
    if(remove.equal == TRUE) {comparison = gsub("=",  "",  comparison)}
    if(remove.zero  == TRUE) {comparison = gsub("0",  "",  comparison)}
    if(swap.colon   == TRUE) {comparison = gsub(":",  "-", comparison)}
    if(swap.vs      == TRUE) {comparison = gsub("vs", "-", comparison)}
    
    names(Comparison) = comparison
    
    if(print.comp == TRUE) 
    {Y = data.frame(Comparisons = names(Comparison), 
                    p.value = p.value, Value=Comparison,
                    Threshold=threshold)
    cat("\n", "\n")
    print(Y)
    cat("\n", "\n")}
    
    MCL = multcompLetters(Comparison, ...)
    
    Group      = names(MCL$Letters)
    Letter     = as.character(MCL$Letters)
    MonoLetter = as.character(MCL$monospacedLetters)
    
    Z = data.frame(Group, Letter, MonoLetter)
    
    return(Z)
  }
```

Here's a portion of my data (output from another program):

```
dummy_df <-data.frame(target = c("A1","A1","A1","A1","A1","A1","A2","A2","A2","A2","A2","A2","A3","A3","A3","A3","A3","A3","A4","A4","A4","A4","A4","A4"),
                      comparison = c("a - b","a - c","a - d","b - c","b - d","c - d","a - b","a - c","a - d","b - c","b - d","c - d","e - c","e - d","e - f","c - d","c - f","d - f","e - c","e - d","e - f","c - d","c - f","d - f"),
                      significant = c("Yes","No","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","No","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","No","Yes","Yes","No","No","No","No","No","No"),
                      p.val = c( 0.04,0.06,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.06,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.06,0.04,0.04,0.06,0.06,0.06,0.06,0.06,0.06))
```

My code looks like this

```
i <- 1
targets <- data.frame(Genes = unique(dummy_df$target))
df <- data.frame()
df1 <- data.frame(Group = "No", Letter ="significant", MonoLetter = "differences")
 
while (i<=nrow(targets)) {
print(i)
df2 <-cldList(p.val~comparison, data = subset.data.frame(dummy_df, dummy_df$target==targets[i,]), threshold = 0.05)
   print(df2)
    
    df2$target <- targets[i,]
    #print(df2)
    
    df <- rbind(df, df2)
    
     i <- i+1
  }
```

I tried adding `if (nrow(df2)==0) {df2 <- df1}` after the `cldList` step to at least have the information about which targets aren't statistically difference, but without success.

Is there a workaround that makes the loop continue through all the targets? Ideally, the `cldList` output with the same letter for all Groups would be the goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the author of the `cldList()` function.

Unfortunately, the looping code you presented isn't working for me.

However, I can address the behavior of `cldList()` when there are no significant differences.  The issue was that `multcompLetters`, which the function relies on, has different output when there are no significant differences.

**EDIT:** The function in the *rcompanion* package has been updated to return a data frame with the same letter for all groups when there are no significant differences. (rcompanion v. 2.4.13, [CRAN.R-project.org/package=rcompanion](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=rcompanion)

```
#### Examples

library(rcompanion)

Comparison = c("A-B", "A-C", "B-C")
Pvalue     = c(0.04, 1, 1)
DataFrame  = data.frame(Comparison, Pvalue)

cldList(Pvalue ~ Comparison, data=DataFrame)

### Group Letter MonoLetter
### 1     A      a         a 
### 2     B      b          b
### 3     C     ab         ab

Comparison2 = c("A-B", "A-C", "B-C")
Pvalue2     = c(1, 1, 1)
DataFrame2  = data.frame(Comparison2, Pvalue2)

cldList(Pvalue2 ~ Comparison2, data=DataFrame2)

### Group Letter MonoLetter
### 1     A      a          a
### 2     B      a          a
### 3     C      a          a
```

Comment: I the revised function works great and will save me a lot of time with the bigger data. Thanks! (I realized I was calling the wrong object in my loop, it's edited now)